# The size of my buffer change when I convert an unsigned char to a string

Tags: c++

I'm having issues with a type conversion that I can't explain.

**Here is what i would like to do**

I have a buffer that I dynamically allocate and i need to convert it to a string in order to use a parsing function from an external library.

**My implementation**

```
unsigned char* msg_data;
msg_data = (unsigned char*)malloc(msg_data_length);
string msg_data_str = std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(_msg_data));
SomeObject myObject;
myObject.ParseFromString(msg_data_str);
```

But here is the thing : my parsing function fails because it receives the wrong size of data.
Let's say that i have a buffer of size `msg_data_length = 10`, the size of my string is `my_data_str.size() = 14`.

I get rid of my problem by using `my_data_str.resize(my_data_length)`
but I would like to understand why the size of `my_data_str` is not directly `msg_data_length`.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Allocate 14 bytes, store `string` value inside and look at contents. I suppose there are 2 or 4 byte prefix (16 or 32 bit value) which says how many chars follow.

Comment: My first guess was that. I didn't check but ty for the advice. The thing is that I don't want the size to change, so the solution of @Joachim works fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the message data is not actually zero-terminated like a C-style string, which leads to undefined behavior when the `std::string` constructor is going out of bounds to find the terminator.

To fix this, use the constructor taking two arguments, the string and the length.

See e.g. [this `std::string` constructor reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string).

Comment: Thanks ! You are right. It is not zero-terminated, as it comes from a stream of raw data.